How to remove contour labels from PartialDependenceDisplay plot
I'm using the PartialDependenceDisplay function from sklearn to visualize the results from a random forest classification. Is there any way to remove the contour labels that are included in the figure?
For the purpose of this question it seems easiest to use this example from the https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/partial_dependence.html#partial-dependence:
from sklearn.datasets import make_hastie_10_2
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.inspection import PartialDependenceDisplay

X, y = make_hastie_10_2(random_state=0)
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=100, learning_rate=1.0,
    max_depth=1, random_state=0).fit(X, y)
features = [(0, 1)]
PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(clf, X, features)

If I was plotting the contours myself I would try something like the code below, but in this case I don't know how to access the ContourSet.
 c  = plt.contour(np.random.random(100).reshape(10,10))
 cl = plt.clabel(c) 
 for label in cl:
        label.remove()

